# array.filter is undefined when looping over objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects where the value i'm trying to find is a number, i'm wanting to return the underlying objects array when the correct number is found, and the value i'm passing to search is type number.

I keep getting "array.filter is undefined" error. I'm assuming it's because the structure is one object and not an array? Whats the best way to do this?

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/gJPHw/220/)

```
  var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj === 2000;
  })[0];

  console.log( obj );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "array" is not an array - its an object

```
var array = {
  "legend": {
     ....
  }
}
```

What you want instead is just read properties of an object - some of them are numeric, which means you'll need the square bracket notation:

```
 var obj = array.legend["2000"];
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJPHw/221/

Comment: @jamec, Damm you're right! Sometimes a different pair of eyes is the best.